# Find $\int\frac{x}{(1+x)(x^4+4)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Find $$\int\frac{x}{(1+x)(x^4+4)}dx$$

---

I tried to do partial fractions.
$$\int\frac{x}{(1+x)(x^4+4)}dx=\int\frac{x+1-1}{(1+x)(x^4+4)}dx=\int\frac{dx}{x^4+4}-\int\frac{dx}{(1+x)(x^4+4)}$$
I am stuck now.I do not know how to integrate now.

Comment: Factorize $x^4 + 4$ using the [Sophie Germain identity](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/SophieGermainIdentity.shtml) and it should solve your woes

Comment: @Brahmagupta: Are you sure you got the partial fractions correct? $\dfrac{x}{(1+x)(x^4+4)} = \dfrac{3-x}{20 \left(x^2-2 x+2\right)}+\dfrac{x+1}{4 \left(x^2+2 x+2\right)}-\dfrac{1}{5 (x+1)}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

$$x^4+4=(x^2+2)^2-(2x)^2=\cdots$$

Now use Partial Fraction Decomposition,
$$\dfrac x{(x+1)(x^4+4)}=\dfrac A{x+1}+\dfrac{Bx+C}{x^2+2x+2}+\dfrac{Dx+E}{x^ 2-2x+2}$$

Write $$\dfrac{Dx+E}{x^ 2-2x+2}=\dfrac{D(x-1)}{(x-1)^2+1^2}+\dfrac{D+E}{(x-1)^2+1^2}$$